# Eclipse gradle integration

Tags: eclipse, gradle, build

Do eclipse project->build, project-build all, project->clean commands work with gradle projects? If they do, which gradle tasks do they invoke and where is console output.

Thank you!
--- Vadim

Comment: Do you have Eclipse BuildShip (integration with Gradle) installed? Also, please refine your question as if you're asking, it's most likely because you have a problem. The problem should be in the question.

Comment: Yes, I do have buildship installed. With Buildship installed, what is being run when I use eclipse's clean/build/build all/etc commands? are gradle tasks being run? Which ones? Where can I see the console output?

Answer (score 0):

An eclipse project build/clean does normally use the integrated eclipse java compiler instead of gradle build system. So your build output is inside /bin folder. The eclipse internal build is very fast because of the eclipse delta compiler etc.

When you build your projects in gradle normally /build/** folders are used for gradle output results.

So you got "two worlds" / two output folders. This is important to understand when you are using console parallel with eclipse. Some gradle integrations for eclipse try to change this default behaviour and are adding special Builders to call gradle for build/clean etc. but - in my opinion - this will increase build time too much when your projects are growing bigger.

Instead of buildship you could also use EGradle IDE (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/egradle-ide).

Its lightweight, fast and compfortable. You can very simple call tasks in this eclipse integration for gradle. More information can be found at https://github.com/de-jcup/egradle/wiki/Help